# How to export complex array from python to tiff file for IDL

Tags: python, save, tiff, idl-programming-language

I have a complex 2D numpy array and I would like to save it as a tiff file to import it into IDL.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `tifffile.imsave('complex.tif', complex_numpy_array)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is interesintg for you to  save directly a .sav file (IDL format) from numpy using the package pIDLy (https://github.com/anthonyjsmith/pIDLy).

For me, it works like that:

```
#starting IDL
idl = pidly.IDL()

#save the file with the save method of idle
idl.pro('save',variable,FILENAME=name_file)

#clossing IDL session
idl.close()
```